# How to build a node express api with a key value format for arguments?

Tags: node.js, api, express, mean

I can follow the suggested express format which is:

```
api.com/users/:id
```

But I need to make it match the existing api pattern which is:

```
api.com/users?id=id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access query strings from the **req.query** object:

```
app.get('/users', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.query.id);
});
```

Here are the docs for [req.query](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.query).